# dropbox api - Which dropbox icon should I choose?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am an android developer.I decided to include dropbox api in my project.

Regarding dropbox icon, does anyone know what type of icons should I choose for dropbox?

Is there an android `dropbox image for pics / files`?

Can someone please advice me what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: https://www.dropbox.com/branding

There is a link on the page for downloading their icons.

Answer (score 0):

Try your luck in http://images.google.com/advanced_image_search, you can filter with right type of license. My only suggestion is, don't use glassy icon like the other OS.